# How to reduce spacing around \odot?

Tags: math-mode

I am struggling trying to keep my equations in 1 line in a two column document. Here's what it looks like:

[image]

I think it would help if im able to reduce the spacing around the `\odot` operation. How can I achieve this?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{4}
    \hat{y}_{\Psi}^t &= \Psi(h^t_\text{h}) + \hat{y}^{t-1} \hspace{-\textwidth} \\
    \hat{y}^t_{\Phi,s,i} &= \Phi([\hat{y}_{\Psi}^t \odot m,x_i^t,\mathrm{BPS}_i,s])\hspace{-\textwidth} \label{eq:doublegrabnets} \\
    \hat{y}^{'t} &= \hat{y}_{\Psi}^t\odot m_l &&+ \textstyle\sum_{i} \hat{\alpha}^t_{l,i}\hat{y}^t_{\Phi,l,i} &&\odot m_l + \hat{\alpha}^t_{l,\text{h}}\hat{y}_{\Psi}^t &&\odot m_l \label{eq:larmupdate} \\
    \hat{y}^t &= \hat{y}^{'t} \odot m_r &&+ \textstyle\sum_{i} \hat{\alpha}^t_{r,i}\hat{y}^t_{\Phi,r,i} &&\odot m_r + \hat{\alpha}^t_{r,\text{h}}\hat{y}^{'t} &&\odot m_r \label{eq:rarmupdate}
\end{alignat}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, add code that reproduces the desired equations. Anyway, reducing those spaces would not help.

Comment: Does `{\oplus}` give the spacing you have in mind? (To me the spacing around the `\oplus` looks OK as is.)

Comment: Unrelated, please don't use `_\text{h}`, (1) the macro `\text` does not do what you think it does, use `\mathrm{h}` instead, (2) don't rely on `_\text{h}` working, use proper braces `_{...}`, it might work now, but there is no guarantee for it to keep doing so.

Comment: Removing the spacing on `\odot`  will not help much and will just make the equations harder to read. Why are you aligning in so many places to begin with?

Comment: This code doesn't reproduce the issue. By the way, it's `\hat{y}'^{t}`, not `\hat{y}^{'t}` that produces wrong output.

Comment: `\textstyle\sum_` applies text style to the whole expression, not just the `\sum` so the left of your equation is in display style and the right is in text style

Comment: I added `[twocolumn]` so that your posted code is an example of your issue.